# Error: Unreachable code detected ionic 3 weather app

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

Ok, so I am following along the traversy media tutorial on ionic 3, and when i get to the part where you create a provider I get and error that says unreachable code detected in here:

`.map((res: Response) => res.json() );`

and it also says on *typescript*

> cannot find the name 'map' did you mean 'Map'?

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class WeatherProvider {
  apiKey = "89cca14f4ffcd27d602ad5e587f8e17f";
  url;

 constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
   console.log('Hello WeatherProvider Provider');
   this.url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
 }



 getWeather(city, country){
 return this.http.get(this.url+city+','+country);
   .map((res: Response) => res.json() );
 }

}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you shouldn't have the semicolon here (typo?): ` return this.http.get(this.url+city+','+country);` - I'm assuming the `.map(...)` should come directly after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement in `getWeather()` is making the `.map()` unreachable. You should make the return statement the last statement in the function.

Comment: actually the problem gets resolve just by removing the semicolon on the return line, however if i put the return line last like you suggested i get the same problem

Comment: actually, that's why my answer is correct. Removing the semicolon actually makes your return the last statement because JS removes whitespace and compresses the code into a single line making the return statement one expression.

Comment: @lcrimsonl you can read about it here: https://crockford.com/javascript/encyclopedia/#automatic%20semicolon%20insertion
More specifically: 
In the next example, a ; semicolon is not inserted after c because there is not a syntax error.

a = b + c
(d + e).print()
It is understood to mean

a = b + c(d + e).print();
which might be quite different than the intention. It is not wise to rely on semicolon insertion. It can mask errors and it can cause errors.
---- 
So therefore, you can take the behavior of semicolon insertion and ...continued below

Comment: deduce that JS is just chugging right down the line. That's why when you take the semicolon out, your code compiles as expected. It's kinda round-about but that's what's happening.